# How to make a 3D viewer in a mixed QML + C++ application

Tags: qtquick2

I am writing an application that will let users pick stuff from a scrollable list of objects(represented as icons in the list). Then drop them to a 3D Viewer. Then the user clicks ‘Play’ and these objects move.

Its for a physics simulation where the objects to be added are in the list. So the interface is quite simple and I wanted to create it in QML. The simulation classes are in C++ (Bullet Physics). I am planning to make a 3D Viewer where the objects can be seen moving(following the laws of physics), as a QML Extension Plugin implemented in C++.

The interface is this:[image]

The middle light gray area is where the 3D viewer will come in. The scene will be quite simple for now with max 15 to 20 objects scattered about.

I would like to know the best way to do this. Here are the options I have found so far:

1. Write a QQuickFramebufferObject based class: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html#details
   This provides a FBO already and I have to implement the renderer in a QQuickFramebufferObject ::Renderer class: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html
2. Extend QQuickItem http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html
   But this means I have to deal with Qt's scene graph and also create a FBO for some reason. I am not sure if this will result in my rendering going into the correct area of the window(gray area)
3. Extend from QQuickPaintedItem and implement paint()
4. Extend QDeclarativeItem which seems to be deprecated.

I would like to keep the drawing efficient and as fast as possible.